# Who did Rae Sloane send to Kashyyyk?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-aftermath

I just finished reading *Star Wars Aftermath: Life Debt*.

At one point, Han and company pass through an Imperial blockade on their way to Kashyyyk. An Admiral from a star destroyer calls Rae Sloane to tell her about a suspicious ship landing on the planet. She realizes who was piloting that ship and she wants to investigate, but Gallius Rax talks her out of this idea. The scene ends with Sloane first calling the star destroyer to cancel her order, and then calling "*someone*" to investigate on her behalf.

I admit that I have only skimmed through some of paragraphs as I was craving for action, but I completely missed any followup to this story line.

Who did she call? What role did this person play during events on Kashyyyk?